# Stored procedure is working fine. But when use in SSRS report, I hit an error - Divide by zero error encountered

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

My stored procedure is working fine when run in SQL Server, but I'm getting an 
error when I used it in SSRS.

Below is my stored procedure. I can't find where I'm hitting the error. 
But I think it must be near the `Case` statement.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_rptAveragePricesFleet] 
    @ShipManagerID bigint,
    @PeriodFrom DateTime,
    @PeriodTo DateTime
AS
    DECLARE @ExchangeRate decimal(18, 2)
    DECLARE @tblTotalPrice TABLE
                           (
                               ShipID bigint, ShipName varchar(MAX), 
                               CategoryGroupDesc varchar(100), 
                               ManagerName varchar(50), 
                               PriceGram decimal(18, 2), 
                               QuantityGr decimal(18, 2), 
                               TotalPrice decimal(18, 2)
                           )
    DECLARE @tblAVGPrice TABLE 
                         (
                             ShipID bigint, ShipName varchar(MAX), 
                             CategoryGroupDesc varchar(100), 
                             ManagerName varchar(50), 
                             AveragePrice decimal(18, 2), 
                             QuantityGr decimal(18, 2)
                         )

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @ExchangeRate = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 ExchangeRate
                                FROM tblExchangeRate ER 
                                INNER JOIN dbo.tblOrderInfoHeader OIH ON ER.FromCurrencyID = OIH.OrderCurrencyID 
                                INNER JOIN dbo.tblShips S ON OIH.ShipID = S.ShipID
                                INNER JOIN dbo.tblShipsManagerOwner SM ON S.ShipsManagerOwnerID = SM.ShipsManagerOwnerID         
                                WHERE FromCurrencyID = OIH.SupplierCurrencyID
                                  AND ToCurrencyID =  201
                                  AND EffectivityDate <= OIH.OrderDate 
                                  AND SM.ShipsManagerOwnerID = @ShipManagerID
                                  AND OIH.DeliveryDate >= @PeriodFrom
                                  AND OIH.DeliveryDate <= @PeriodTo
                                  AND OIH.IsCashOrder = 0
                                  AND OIH.OrderStatusID <> 11
                              ORDER BY EffectivityDate DESC), 1)

    INSERT INTO @tblTotalPrice (ShipID, ShipName, CategoryGroupDesc, ManagerName, PriceGram, QuantityGr, TotalPrice)
        SELECT 
            S.ShipID, S.ShipName,
            CG.CategoryGroupDesc,
            SM.ManagerName,
            CASE 
                WHEN OIH.OrderCurrencyID = 201 
                   THEN SUM(OID.PriceRequestPrice / OID.WeightInGrams)
                ELSE SUM(OID.PriceRequestPrice * @ExchangeRate / OID.WeightInGrams)
            END AS PriceGram,
            SUM(OID.OrderQuantity * OID.WeightInGrams) AS QuantityGr,
            CASE 
               WHEN OIH.OrderCurrencyID = 201 
                  THEN SUM((OID.PriceRequestPrice / OID.WeightInGrams) * (OID.OrderQuantity * OID.WeightInGrams)) 
               ELSE SUM(((OID.PriceRequestPrice * @ExchangeRate) / OID.WeightInGrams) * (OID.OrderQuantity * OID.WeightInGrams)) 
            END AS TotalPrice
        FROM 
            dbo.tblShips S
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.tblOrderInfoHeader OIH ON S.ShipID = OIH.ShipID 
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.tblOrderInfoDetail OID ON OIH.OrderInfoHeaderID = OID.OrderInfoHeaderID
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.tblSuppliersProducts SP ON OID.SuppliersProductsID = SP.SuppliersProductsID
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.tblProducts P ON SP.ProductID = P.ProductID
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.tblSubCategory SC ON P.SubCategoryID = SC.SubCategoryID
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.tblCategory C ON SC.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.tblCategoryGroup CG ON C.CategoryGroupID = CG.CategoryGroupID
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.tblShipsManagerOwner SM ON S.ShipsManagerOwnerID = SM.ShipsManagerOwnerID
        WHERE 
            (SM.ShipsManagerOwnerID = @ShipManagerID)
            AND OIH.DeliveryDate >= @PeriodFrom
            AND OIH.DeliveryDate <= @PeriodTo
            AND (OIH.IsCashOrder = 0)
            AND (OIH.OrderStatusID <> 11)
       GROUP BY 
           S.ShipID, S.ShipName, CG.CategoryGroupDesc, SM.ManagerName, OIH.OrderCurrencyID
       ORDER BY 
           CategoryGroupDesc


    INSERT INTO @tblAVGPrice(ShipID, ShipName, CategoryGroupDesc, ManagerName, AveragePrice, QuantityGr)
        SELECT  
            ShipID, ShipName,
            CategoryGroupDesc,
            ManagerName, 
            SUM(TotalPrice / (QuantityGr / 1000)) as AveragePrice, 
            QuantityGr
        FROM 
            @tblTotalPrice
        GROUP BY
            ShipID, ShipName,CategoryGroupDesc, ManagerName,  QuantityGr
        ORDER BY 
            CategoryGroupDesc

    SELECT 
        ShipID, ShipName,
        CategoryGroupDesc,
        ManagerName,
        AveragePrice, QuantityGr
    FROM   
        @tblAVGPrice
    GROUP BY
        ShipID, ShipName,CategoryGroupDesc, ManagerName, AveragePrice,  QuantityGr
    ORDER BY 
        CategoryGroupDesc
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this column in your temp table:

```
SUM(OID.OrderQuantity * OID.WeightInGrams) AS QuantityGr
```

Then you use it in this calculation:

```
SUM(TotalPrice / (QuantityGr / 1000)) as AveragePrice
```

So if either `OrderQuantity` or `OID.WeightInGrams` are ever 0 that would cause the error.

To address your initial question, SSRS doesn't change the behavior of the procedure in any way. So perhaps you were running it with different parameter values when you got the error? Or were you doing other division in the report expressions that could have caused the error? Just some things to look for.

Comment: Hi StevenWhite. I am running the ssrs with the same parameter. That's why I don't know what is causing the error. I'll check my proc regarding your suggestion. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi StevenWhite - Both of your answer is correct but since trubs answered first. I'll mark his answer as the solution.  I already solved the problem. The OID.OrderQuantity in some items are 0 and causing the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It can only be your parameters that are causing the issue,

Either OrderQuantity =0 or WeightInGrams = 0 when your proc is running.

can your write out your params from inside the proc?

ps: You don't need the case statements as your query because the exchange rate will be 1 if the oic.OrderCurrencyId = 201.

Also, @ExchangeRate could still be null if the inner query returns no records (ie no rows)

try it out

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(40)
SELECT @x = ISNULL(error,'nothing returned') FROM sysmessages t WHERE 1=2
PRINT isnull(@x,'what happened to my data?')
```

Comment: Hi trubs. But I have the ISNULL in my ExchangeRate which will return 1 if no row is returned. I'll will try doing your suggestion. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi trubs. OrderQuantity for some items are 0 and causing the issue. Thank you so much. Have a good day.

Comment: it was actually @StevenWhite that responded first.  (when I submitted my answer his was already there)

Comment: thanks SQLNuisance for playing fair. I changed and mark his as answer if you don't mind. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to add a zero check any time I am using a division function, especially if a field has the potential to be zero (i.e.OID.WeightInGrams).   In your CASE statement, add to it by telling it what to do if the field you are dividing by is zero.

```
 CASE 
     WHEN (OIH.OrderCurrencyID = 201 and OID.WeightInGrams = 0) then 0
     WHEN (OIH.OrderCurrencyID = 201 and OID.WeightInGrams <> 0)
     THEN SUM(OID.PriceRequestPrice / OID.WeightInGrams)
     ELSE SUM(OID.PriceRequestPrice * @ExchangeRate / OID.WeightInGrams)
 END AS PriceGram,
```

Comment: Hi Kerry. Thank you for the tips but I already fixed the issue. Thanks anyways.